# Magento + Google Shopping: item not found while Synchronizing

Tags: magento

When i select and add products from 'View Available Products' , products are added sucessfully and shows "Total of 1 product(s) have been added to Google Content.",
but it do not show up in my Google Shopping, Do i have to wait for some time to appear that product on Google shopping?,

and when i select "Google Content items" and submit for Synchronization , it will  delete item from google content grid and show this message , "Total of 1 items(s) have been deleted; total of 0 items(s) have been updated."

i check with the googleshopping logs in Magento and it show like

```
 [body] => 
[content_type] => 
[remaining_redirects] => 
[response] => Zend_Http_Response Object
    (
        [version:protected] => 1.1
        [code:protected] => 404
        [message:protected] => Not Found
        [headers:protected] => Array
            (
                [Content-type] => application/vnd.google.gdata.error+xml
                [Date] => Fri, 01 Feb 2013 10:49:19 GMT
                [Expires] => Fri, 01 Feb 2013 10:49:19 GMT
                [Cache-control] => private, max-age=0
                [X-content-type-options] => nosniff
                [X-frame-options] => SAMEORIGIN
                [X-xss-protection] => 1; mode=block
                [Server] => GSE
                [Connection] => close
            )

        [body:protected] => <errors xmlns='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'><error><domain>sc</domain><code>notfound</code><location type='other'>request</location><internalReason>item not found</internalReason></error></errors>
    )

[__pid] => 24763
```

Any idea whats going wrong.

initially it was showing me error like

Fatal error: Call to a member function getText() on a non-object in /chroot/home/storeaud/store.audioholics.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/GoogleShopping/Model/Service/Item.php on line 64

So by refering this post http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/303448/#t421637, i am able to fix that issue , but now i can not get the product added to Google Shopping in Google Account.

Any Help will be Very much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

OK, after some digging around, I've found that this only causes a problem when the product has expired and no longer exists under the list of products in GMC (Google Merchant Center), therefore it cannot find the product on GMC to sync/delete.

IMO, it should have automatically deleted it from the Magento Google Shopping sync list if product is not found, but eh... it is what it is.

To get around it, you'll need to go into your database and run the following:

DELETE FROM `googleshopping_items` WHERE `expires` < NOW();

This should get rid of all products that have expired, and you should be able to sync fresh !

Comment: I am facing problem while deleting expired products from the magento admin ,under Catalog > Google content > Manage Items. No item is getting delete please help